# T-SQL CASE (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, union

I have a T-SQL query that I need to total out the counts for the `CASE` statements.

I tried to add a UNION but I am getting an error:

> *All queries in an SQL statement containing a UNION operator must have
>   an equal number of expressions in their target lists.*

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Query:

```
SELECT 
   CustomerID, Name, DueDate, 
   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, PaymentDate, DueDate) >= 1 
            THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 
   END AS [Early],
   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, PaymentDate, DueDate) >=0 
            THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 
   END AS [On Time],
   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, PaymentDate, DueDate) = -1 
            THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 
   END AS [Late]
FROM 
    Customers 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, PaymentDate,DueDate), GetDate()) = 1
    AND PaymentAmount= DuesAmount

UNION

SELECT 
    '-Total', '', CustomerID, Name, DueDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, PaymentDate, DueDate) >= 1 
               THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS [Early],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, PaymentDate, DueDate) >= 0 
               THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS [On Time],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, PaymentDate, DueDate) = -1 
               THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS [Late]
FROM 
    Customers
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, PaymentDate,DueDate), GetDate()) = 1
    AND PaymentAmount = DuesAmount
```

Comment: @ruakh I completely agree with your comment. We can only just vote for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says, "All queries in a SQL statement containing a `UNION` operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."  What this means is that each `SELECT` must return the same number of expressions.

In the code sample you gave us, the first `SELECT` statement returns 6 expressions, while the second one returns 8:

```
SELECT CustomerID,                -- 1
       Name,                      -- 2
       DueDate,                   -- 3
       CASE ... END AS [Early],   -- 4
       CASE ... END AS [On Time], -- 5
       CASE ... END AS [Late]     -- 6
...
UNION
SELECT '-Total',                       -- 1
       '',                             -- 2
       CustomerID,                     -- 3
       Name,                           -- 4
       DueDate,                        -- 5
       SUM(CASE ... END) AS [Early],   -- 6
       SUM(CASE ... END) AS [On Time], -- 7
       SUM(CASE ... END) AS [Late]     -- 8
...
```

See how the first `SELECT` returns 6 expressions, but the second returns 8?  In a `UNION`, all the `SELECT` statements must return the same number of expressions.

You can return `NULL` in the first query for columns that don't have a match in the second, if necessary.  For example:

```
SELECT NULL as [RowType],         -- 1
       NULL as [Padding],         -- 2
       CustomerID,                -- 3
       Name,                      -- 4
       DueDate,                   -- 5
       CASE ... END AS [Early],   -- 6
       CASE ... END AS [On Time], -- 7
       CASE ... END AS [Late]     -- 8
...
UNION
SELECT '-Total',                       -- 1
       '',                             -- 2
       CustomerID,                     -- 3
       Name,                           -- 4
       DueDate,                        -- 5
       SUM(CASE ... END) AS [Early],   -- 6
       SUM(CASE ... END) AS [On Time], -- 7
       SUM(CASE ... END) AS [Late]     -- 8
...
```

Also, note that you don't have a comma after the DueDate column.

Comment: Paul thanks for the info.   I am able to run the query now without errors. But I don't see the totals in my results.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, but you might need an `ORDER BY ColumnName` to ensure the total is at the end.  And a `GROUP BY CustomerID` if you want totals by customer.  And you could try `UNION ALL` to be sure the totals aren't somehow being dropped as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks again.  I did find the totals it was being displayed in the middle of the results.  You were right I did have to add an ORDER BY. I had someone else assist me.  Below is the adjustments I had to make to the query to get this to work correctly, thanks again.  
Select * ''
(Select '' as [ColumnName]

)Data

ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN [CustomerID] ='Total'
            THEN 1
            ELSE [CustomerID]
      END

Comment: Good to hear it.  Please accept the answer when you get a chance.